# What is the meaning of "HHhH"?

Tags: title, the-man-with-the-iron-heart

I wonder what "HHhH" means in the alternative title of [The Man with the Iron Heart](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3296908/).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

HHhH is the debut novel of French author Laurent Binet, released in 2010 by Grasset & Fasquelle. The novel recounts *Operation Anthropoid*, the assassination of Nazi leader Reinhard Heydrich in Prague during World War II.

The title is an initialism for **Himmlers Hirn heißt Heydrich** ("Himmler's brain is called Heydrich"), a quip about Heydrich said to have circulated in Nazi Germany. The title was suggested by Binet's publisher, Grasset, instead of the "too sci-fi" working title *Opération Anthropoïde*.